# Replicate a table with div-css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a website wallz.moon.pk, it's a wallpaper collection, on the gallery where I show thumbnails I have created a mouse over effect that for mouse a semi transparent strip is shown over the thumbnail so that user can select an appropriate answer..

I am not very good with DIVs so I put in a table to create the effect I wanted, check it out [here](http://wallz.moon.pk/), I have used the following code:

```
<div id="i551" class="actions">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><h2>Water Bubbles</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="50%">
        <a href="Water+Bubbles.html" class="acthuns">Open Here</a>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
        <a href="Water+Bubbles.html" class="acthuns" target="_blank">
            + New Tab </a>          
    </td>                                   
</tr>                           
</table>                    
</div>
```

My question is how to convert the above Table and used DIVs & CSS styling to get the same effect....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/tNms9/3/

HTML

```
<div id="i551" class="actions">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Water Bubbles</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="Water+Bubbles.html" class="acthuns">Open Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="Water+Bubbles.html" class="acthuns" target="_blank">
            + New Tab </a>            
        </div>          
    </div>                   
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.actions{ width:400px; }
.row { width:100%; overflow:hidden; background:lime; }
.cell {width:45%; padding:10px; float:left; background:orange; }​
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS 2.1, the `display` property have *Table model values* which allows you to set the display of a element to each `<table>` known element : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display#Values

PS : It doesn't work on IE7-.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code will produces the first row of images. You can mess with the percentages to get the white space you want, but here is the basic idea:

CSS:

```
.tile-container {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-2%; /* offsets the first column of tiles */
}
.tile {
   float:left;
   width:23%;
   margin-left:2%;
   margin-bottom:2%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tile-container">
    <div class="tile>
       <!-- Image + other markup goes here -->
    <div>
    <div class="tile>
       <!-- Image + other markup goes here -->
    <div>
    <div class="tile>
       <!-- Image + other markup goes here -->
    <div>
    <div class="tile>
       <!-- Image + other markup goes here -->
    <div>
</div>
```